# How to enter @ and € on a German MacOS installation?

Tags: keyboard

On a German MacOS installation, with a German QWERTZ Keyboard connected to it (third party, not an Apple keyboard), What are the key combinations to enter the symbols '`@`' and '`€`' ?

If there are various options, please mention each of them.

The obvious guess `AltGr+q` for `@` and `AltGr+e` for `€` ain't working, and unfortunately I'm about 200km separated from the Mac that causes the trouble, so your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Mac doesn't use or recognise Alt/Gr as a key. It sees it only as Opt [Alt]. Try Opt/E for € and Opt/L for @ [though these are based on the positions on a Mac keyboard, not Windows remoting into a Mac]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s <kbd>alt+L</kbd> for the @ and  <kbd>alt+E</kbd> for the €.

https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201794

[image: keyboard layout]

Comment: alt+l is not working, represents a dot, alt+e for euro works.

Comment: how do you get the ^ symbol then? **NOTE** I have originally a US keyboard so the degrees/up arrow sign on the top left of your image is actually the <> keys for me.

Comment: @user71207 Does the <kbd><></kbd> key enter the "^" symbol then? I remember, I had this problem once with an external US keyboard using the German layout. I used [karabiner elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) (`brew install karabiner-elements`) to swap those two keys.

Answer (score 5):

If on the Mac you set the Input Source to "German Standard" (and not "German"), then you will have @ produced by Option/alt Q and € by Option/alt E.  That may be how your 3rd party keyboard is printed.

The layout shown in HT201794 reflects an Apple keyboard which corresponds to the "German" input source.  The newest Apple keyboards correspond to German Standard.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately there's an older version of MacOS running, so there was no "German Standard" input source.

Comment: @SePröbläm I can send you a copy to install if you want one if I have your email.

Comment: Thanks Tom, it works with Monterey. So Apple changed from German to German Standard.